# How to plot SVM classifier using RTextTools package?

Tags: r, svm, text-classification

I am using the `RTextTools` package to create a Document Term Matrix, before using the associated container in range of classification models.

I have reviewed the [package information](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RTextTools/RTextTools.pdf) and [associated articles](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/collingwood-jurka-boydstun-etal.pdf) but I cannot find any indication on how to **plot** the results of tuning and predicting the classification models. For example, I am building a linear SVM model using `svm.fit <- train_model(container, "SVM", kernel="linear", cost=1)`. How can I visualise `svm.fit`?

I am ideally looking to obtain similar results as if I was using plot.svm from the e1071 package. However, I cannot use this here as the `class(container)` is `matrix_container` and not an expected data frame.

The code that I am utilising is below. Thanks for your help.

```
    #Create Training Container#
    dtMatrix <- create_matrix(cbind.data.frame(Train.df$Keyword1, Train.df$Keyword2), removeSparseTerms=.998)

    Train_container <- create_container(dtMatrix, Train.df$Result, trainSize=1:10000, virgin=FALSE)

    #Create Validation Container#   
    trace("create_matrix", edit=T)
    Validate_dtMatrix <- create_matrix(cbind.data.frame(Validate.df$Keyword1, Validate.df$Keyword2), originalMatrix=dtMatrix)

    predSize = nrow(Validate.df)
    ValidateContainer <- create_container(Validate_dtMatrix, labels=rep(0,predSize), testSize=1:predSize, virgin=FALSE)

    #===SUPPORT VECTOR MACHINE===#
    svm_linear <- train_model(container, "SVM", kernel="linear", cost=1)

    predict_SVM.Linear <- classify_model(ValidateContainer, svm_linear)
```